# "Error 2023" with "ExecuteExcel4Macro" when fetching a value

Tags: vba, excel

I maintain an Excel-workbook with VBA in it.

The VBA fails when fetching a value from a closed Excel-workbook with "ExecuteExcel4Macro".

**The workbook to fetch the value from is kept on an intranet-webpage.**

```
GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
```

This line of code fails. "Error 2023" is returned.

By tinkering with the code I discovered:

```
tmp = GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
' tmp gets the "Error 2023"-return.
Debug.Print tmp

' Gets the expected data-value from the excel-sheet.
Datum_Homepage = GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
```

If you call it **two** times the first call gets the "Error 2023" and the second call gets the expected value (a date).

How is that possible?

The complete code of the GetValue-function:

```
Public Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref) As Variant

    Dim arg As String

    If Right(path, 1) <> "/" Then path = path & "/"

    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Address(, , xlR1C1)

    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)

End Function
```

Comment: if you assign the value to `tmp` instead of `Datum_Homepage` the second time does it still work? Also we need to see the code for the `GetValue()` function

Comment: @Macro Man : Have added the code of the function to my question. No. It fails because of type-error.

Comment: @st88 what type is `tmp` ? your function Returns a `Variant`. try Setting `tmp` to `variant` too

Comment: We've got no way of reproducing this - but I'm going to blame it on connection speed, the connection hasn't been established in time for the value to be returned the first time you run the code. The second time it has so you're golden. I guess one way to test would be to open the target workbook manually, close it, then run the code and see if you get the error the first time.

Comment: @Doktor OSwaldo I've made tmp of type variant. That's not the reason. I would like to paste the whole code in here but it contains also internal path-literals etc.

Comment: @MacroMan Sure. The whole thing is hard to retrace from the outside. I'm with you with your assumption. Likely the whole thing is caused by some network-latency or something similar.

Comment: @st88 If it's Win7 or later then there are known issues with network based files that _still_ aren't fixed (most common one is opening a workbook and getting 'locked by another user')

Comment: @Macro Man Yep. Everything Windows 7 here. I guess there has someone tried to be a cool programmer without expecting that it could fail that way. ;)